# Develop iOS swift app to mirror into a browser?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, mirror

I am working on a project which is an iOS app using Swift 3. I want to mirror the iPhone screen into a web browser using the app. Please let me know if this is possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. The opposite might be valid, by building a responsive design for the web and display it via `UIWebView` in your iOS app.